# how to count news attached to each user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table `news` `news_id` `user_id` and `users` `user_id` `user_name`
I want a mysql query to count the news attached to each user
something like

```
mad_man = 5 news
me = 102 news
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest three words for you: `SELECT`, `COUNT` and `JOIN` look it up.

**Per request**

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(n.news_id)
  FROM users u
  JOIN news  n on u.user_id = n.user_id
 GROUP BY u.user_id
```

This should count all the news for each user in the specified tables.

Comment: but i can not write it, please write it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, users.user_name
FROM news join users ON news.user_id=users.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_name
```